# How to make a file a part of Joomla?

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions, joomla1.7

This question may seem a bit stupid, but i'm new to Joomla!

And i am editing a current component which i want at some point to call a small php
file that outputs data.
Now in that file i want to use joomla classes and functions for the database
like setQuery and etc.

and i want it to read the joomla prefix ( #__ ).
and the file is created by me, so i wondered what i need to include and how.

Can anyone tell me how to do that?

Thanks in advance,
Eric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well alghimo answer lead me into writing this  :

```
    define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(__FILE__));
define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );

/* Create the Application */
$mainframe =& JFactory::getApplication('site');
```

But as mentoined. not recommended on doing that.

Answer (score 1):

It would be better not to include "external" php files, I mean files out of the Joomla structure. But if you still want to do it, you can just include that php file from anywhere you need it, and you will have all Joomla classes and functions available as long as you include that file from another Joomla tile ( maybe your component entry point, a controller, a model, view, etc.. ).
Besides, if your file outputs data, the best place to include it would be from inside a template in your component. If you use it at any other place, you should get the output for that file ( for example, with ob_start(), ob_get_contents() methods ), and save them to some kind of variable to output it from a template.
I guess you probably already know how to include that file, but if for example your file is inside a folder "mylibs" inside the joomla root, you should include it like this:

```
include JPATH_ROOT . DS . 'mylibs' . DS . 'myfile.php';
```

Why is the reason you need to include that file and it's not possible to render it as a template?

I hope it helped.

Comment: I don't wish to include it, i wish to call it with an XmlHtppRequest call

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use an extension like Sourcer or Jumi

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/edition/custom-code-in-content

Good for getting started before you write 'real' Joomla installable components, modules, plugins etc...

Comment: Hi idea34, i don't need to put code in content. i have a component i just wanna add a small php file that's being called by an XmlHttpRequest.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way would be an output override. [Take a look at the documentation](http://docs.joomla.org/Understanding_Output_Overrides). This way you don't have to edit a core joomla extension (of course, now that I look a little closer you don't say your editing a core extension). Anyway, output overrides are pretty cool, the use the functionality of an extension but you get to do the final modification.

In your current template folder create a folder called 'html', then take a look at the link (or another template, like beez) to determine the structure of the folder the particular extension you're overriding. Then you can call the script from within that override with all the joomla functionality, and without hacking the core.